# Server side alerts for client side app

Tags: apache-flex, email, adobe, client

Here's the scenario:

User interacts with Adobe flex webpage to configure reports based on some data stored server side.  They configure their view and have THAT view emailed to them daily.

I've got the report builder, the part I'm trying to figure out is how to render the report server side and send it out as email (native flex functionality?  convert to html?  take screenshot?  assume something is running client side?...)

Please help me with some ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the title of this is misleading. I originally thought you wanted the server to push notifications to clients (e.g., server-going-down, etc..).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a similar question where I explain an approach for capturing screen elements in a Flex application and pushing them down to the server.

[Flex: Render an unrealized UIComponent to BitmapData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313857/flex-render-an-unrealized-uicomponent-to-bitmapdata/1331930#1331930)

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful.

One clarification: are you suggesting that you don't need to render the component? or do you pretty much have to run a desktop version (AIR) of the web-app on the server?

Comment: No, what I am suggesting is capturing the BitmapData of the component in the Flex application and sending that data to the server, so the image can be included in the PDF that will be generated there.

In terms of rendering, even if you set visible=false, if you add the component as a child of another UIComponent the component will render and its BitmapData will be available.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this: http://www.alivepdf.org/

It's relatively easy to get started with. (If you dig around the web, there's also libraries for generating JPG and PNG from your flash/flex view if you like. )

Once generated, you can send the data to the server for storage & email.