# Generate a flex image from a hidden component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, capture

I'm trying to put an image, generated from some text, in a [RichEditableText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/RichEditableText.html). Since it's a styled text, I thought about putting it another RichEditableText, style it, then print it to a [Bitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/langref/flash/display/Bitmap.html) to use as source for InlineGraphicsElement.

I use the following code to do that

```
var txt:RichEditableText = new RichEditableText();
txt.text = name;
// Appliy given styles to the text flow of input rich editable text
createApplyNamedStyle(name, styles).call(null, txt.textFlow);
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(txt.width, txt.height);
bitmapData.draw(txt);
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
```

Unfortunatly, when called, it displays an error stack

```
ArgumentError: Error #2015: BitmapData non valide.
at flash.display::BitmapData()
at RichTextEditor/getTagImage()[E:\FlexWorkspace\Test\src\RichTextEditor.mxml:74]
at RichTextEditor/insertTag()[E:\FlexWorkspace\Test\src\RichTextEditor.mxml:154]
```

I suspect it is due to the fact that my RichEditableText, not being in visible component, is not laid out.
How can I ensure it is properly laid out ?

And am i doing the right thing to transform my text into an image ?

Comment: From the debugger, I can tell you both width and height are `0`, which is the reason why the BitmapData can't be created.
In my old Java world, I would have done a call to pack() (or something like that) to force the component layout. But here, it does not seems to exist. So, how can I make my component drawable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right; since the text is not on the display list, it is never validated and hence has 0 height and width.

A typical workaround is to add the item to the display list and then remove it immediatley.  A little more discussion in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313857/flex-render-an-unrealized-uicomponent-to-bitmapdata).

Comment: Notice that with Flex 4, teh aforementionned solution must be a little modified : 
Application.application has been replaced by FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication
and addChild has been deprecated in favor of addElement.
Anyway, your reply gave me all the answers I needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should trace txt.width and txt.height. They must be at least greater or equal to one. It does not matter if a DisplayObject is visible or not.